# Django extend User model, want additional inline editing for extended model

Tags: django, inline, extend

I have extended the django user model with a "Member" model. I would like to be able to administer (on admin site) the user - all data from both models. I need the email and name from User, but everything else is from "Member". I have set it up so that I can get all the data on one form, but I cannot continue to add related (child) information to the "Member" as I typically would if it was not being displayed as an inline model of user. Here is my attempt at doing this. It currently works to show User + Member, but cannot show SaleItems (for a Member).

```
from DjangoSite.ManageProducts.models import Member, SaleItem
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import User

# cannot view this data from SaleItem model
class MemSalesInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = SaleItem
    fk_name = 'Seller'

class MemberProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Member
    fk_name = 'user'
    # this does not work
    inlines = [
                MemSalesInline,
            ]

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [MemberProfileInline,]

try:
    admin.site.unregister(User)
except admin.sites.NotRegistered:
    pass

admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 2):

There a great tutorial that describes how to do this:
http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/06/django-tips-extending-user-model/

Basically you can use the AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE to connect your User and Member models. The sample code calls the extended User model UserProfile, which you may want to consider doing as well.

Here's the code from the tutorial:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField()
    home_address = models.TextField()
    phone_numer = models.PhoneNumberField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)

# In Settings.py

AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'myapp.UserProfile'
```

You can now access your extended user model as follows:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
u = User.objects.get(pk=1)
user_address = u.get_profile().home_address
```

"There’s a method on the built-in User model called get_profile(), which keys off this setting; if AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE is defined, then calling get_profile() on any User will return the associated object from your custom class."

Comment: thank you, that is how I have it setup already. I am now wanting to manage the User + Member + Member child records in the django admin site but there seem to be some limitations.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution where I can search for my Members by User.email, user.first_name, or user.last_name and get back Member records + child records - and still easily get back to the User record if I need to. The issue I was having was that I needed to be able to find my Members by User fields. Instead of modifying the User admin site (django's auth_user), I modified my Member admin site (Member being my extension of django's User).

**admin.py**

```
from DjangoSite.ManageProducts.models import Member, SaleItem
from django.contrib import admin

class MemSalesInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = SaleItem
    fk_name = 'Seller'

class MemberAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ['__str__', 'lname', 'fname'] # fname, lname not sortable
        raw_id_fields = ("user",)
        #this allows search "members" by User fields.
        search_fields = ['user__email', 'user__last_name', 'user__first_name']
    # include any child records here - child of "Member"
    inlines = [MemSalesInline,]

admin.site.register(Member, MemberAdmin)
```

**models.py**

```
class Member(models.Model):
    MemberID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Country = models.ForeignKey(dmCountry, blank=True, null=True)
    # plus more additional member info...
    # these allow me to view email, last name and first name in the Member admin list page.
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.user.email
    def lname(self):
        return "%s" % self.user.last_name
    def fname(self):
        return "%s" % self.user.first_name
```